# Android find repeat values in ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Got an ArrayList like that. Wanna find how many values are repeated:
Example: person:4 times , girl:4 times

```
public ArrayList<String> new_contains_all= new ArrayList<>();
```

...

```
[[laying, beautiful, brushing, group, young, head, bed, close, couple, female, teeth, white, indoor, pair, holding, sunglasses, stuffed, wearing, posing, dress, person, hair, standing, looking, girl, red, playing, made, top, woman, lady, hat, clothing, goggles, people],
     [person, hair, young, shirt, looking, phone, girl, white, glasses, food, sunglasses, wearing, woman, hat], [blue, beautiful, person, cake, standing, young, shirt, black, female, board, girl, white, photo, holding, ready, wearing, top, posing, woman, lady, smiling, clothing, dress, suitcase], [street, clock, light, stop, sign, red, text, sitting,
     man, photo, traffic], [blue, person, young, looking, phone, sitting, female, girl, photo, computer, using, red, laptop, holding, glasses, food, sunglasses, wearing, top, woman, lady, hat]]
```

Notify that the Array have 5 elements inside.

Already tried this, that should be working for simple ArrayList but with more than 1 string per element its creepy, i know the solution must implement another bucle inside key, but so tired for today :/ maybe someone blinks my mind :P

```
List<String> l = new_contains_all;
Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>(l);
for (String key : s) {
    int count = Collections.frequency(l, key);
    if (count > 1)
        System.out.println("Found '" + key + "' " + count + " times."+"key: "+key.toString()+"l: "+l.toString());
}
```

Comment: Hint: really bad naming you got there. A) you dont use _ for java names (except for SOME_CONSTANT) B) single character names are simply bad; their only place would be some for loop int counter i, j, ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just was a test with random names, and @marmor isnt the same issue, ofc i already saw this entry

Answer (score 0):

You almost solved your problem, but there is one subtle bug in your code:

```
Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>(l);
```

The core property of a **Set** is: it doesn't allow for duplicates. Thus this one call simply removes all duplicates from that input list l.

Thus: all frequencies will be **one**.

So, instead, you can do:

```
for (String singleWord: new_contains_all) {
  count = Collections.frequency(new_contains_all, singleWord);
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind help @GhosCat, but isnt working, i have the same issue, my ArrayList is a bit different : Here is the output with your change: http://pastebin.com/PTUn4rN7 

SimpleWord sometimes have more values as you could see on the top, but isnt working fine for only one (text) or more values ..

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure where your problem is. You see, the information you are providing here is simply **unclear**.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ... and then provide exactly that information! And, just guessing: are you sure that you have a single flat list of strings; and not some list of lists?

Comment: +1 and thanks, me first incoming structure is a ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> and trying to solve this problem i moved in a single ArrayList<String> wich produce, this kind of list of single and sometimes more than one item.

Comment: Of course, you cant iterate a list of list like a flat list. But again; your input is still unclear. You should update your question to **show** the data structure you are actually dealing with. We cant help you with problems that you dont lay out clearly to us.